# Android - start AlarmManager after reboot

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

AlarmManeger doesn't start after reboot but it should.
How can I do it?
AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmEngine.AlarmManagerHelper" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        setAlarms(context);
    }

public static void setAlarms(Context context)
{
    cancelAlarms(context);
    AlarmDBHelper dbHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(context);
    List<AlarmModel> alarms =  dbHelper.getAlarms();

        for (AlarmModel alarm : alarms)
        {
                PendingIntent pIntent = createPendingIntent(context, alarm);
...
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it moved app to the phone's memory.

I replace this:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal" >
```

On this:

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly" >
```